# how to show any qt window when new channel Enable&DisableBS(1)

Tags: qt

i want to show channel name as msg on qtwindow when i switch between channels. i want to show this msg for longer time but it gets disappears after a second. QTimer is not helping me to do this. i also tries below mentioned event handers functions

```
((TextWindow *)m_pTextWindow)->DisplayDialogTV(l_Channel);
//THIS MY TEXT WINDOW WHICH CONTAINS MY MSG.

QApplication::exec();
QApplication::processEvents();
QApplication::flushX ();
```

MY AIM IS TO DISPLAY MSG FOR LONGER TIME. BUT IT GETS DISAPPEARS IN A SECOND.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow...

Because the class and method you describe as `TextWindow::DisplayDialogTV()` is not part of Qt (but rather your own project), it is not possible to know what is going on here.  Take a look at this essay on writing a "Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example":

http://sscce.org/

Anyway...do you mean you have a timer-based solution that puts the text up and then later takes it down, but the timer signals are happening more rapidly than you expect?  Are you simply laying text down and then immediately seeing it get overwritten when you expect it to stay there until you tell it to go away?

If you used [QPainter::drawText()](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/stable/qpainter.html#drawText) to put text on top of a widget that is drawing several frames of video per second, then you'll have to keep doing that for each frame if you want the message to stay.  Unless you layer a widget on top of the movie widget, then obviously the next frame to come along will overwrite whatever you drew.  You can solve this by creating a [QStaticText](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qstatictext.html) widget and having it float on top of your video window.  Then you can toggle it as visible or invisible.